# Some "link-only" answers are actually appropriate

Tags: discussion, not-an-answer, link-only-answers

During LQP review I generally flag link-only answers for deletion. However, I've run across several answers recently where the question describes a situation resulting from a bug that is logged in a bug tracking system, to which the link points.  For example:

See https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/8411414

That specific post may not be the *best* example, but I can't seem to find another one at present.

I've benefited several times from finding these types of links in SO, and it seems silly to duplicate a lot of what may be a moving target in SO.  In fact, since the bug is often still being worked on, copying anything from the bug tracker to the answer on SO runs the risk of being invalidated by further research by the maintainers.

So... it seems when the answer to a questions is "It's a bug, here's a link to the tracker", a link-only answer is the best choice.

Comments?

Comment: I'd suggest changing the title, since strictly speaking "it's a bug" is enough to keep it from being link-only anyway.

Comment: @NathanTuggy You and I know that, but I have recently seen several such answers on the way to being deleted as "link-only".  Maybe we need better education for the community on what constitutes a link-only answer.

Comment: Yeah, it's often pretty subtle. I spend a fair amount of time in LQP myself rescuing not-actually-NAA posts and commenting to explain why they shouldn't be deleted.

Comment: Links can go bad, and bug-report pages do change. In my opinion it makes sense to briefly quote the relevant current state of the bug, then link to the page you quoted saying something like, "For a current report on the issue, check <this page>".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The fact that there is a link in an answer doesn't mean an answer is a link **only** answer.

If you (would) remove the fluff and then the link, and there is nothing left  then it is a link only answer. In your example you would be left at least with the statement that this is a bug in MySQL and that would be good to know if you hit it in your program.

The only link only answers that I have seen that are appropriate for the questions is when the question is inappropriate and asks for references in the internet. Those are not the kind of questions we want to have here, as they, combined with their answers, are not self-contained.

That has nothing to do with the link pointing to relevant and/or useful material. I even have a few links in my browsers bookmarks that I took from link only answers.

Comment: As I said in a comment on the question, we need better community education on what should be closed as a link-only answer.  I fear it's being too broadly applied.

Comment: The classic: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Answer (score 3):

I think it is wrong to dogmatically follow *any* policy without trying to understand the reasoning behind it and recognizing there are always exceptions.  There are situations where a link is appropriate.

Here's an example I stumbled on today where a link answer is perfectly appropriate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21811774/116614 (ironic considering that a very similar question was answered in a similar way here and received lots of upvotes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22445313/116614)

[image: GitHub Sample Deleted Post]

The question is specifically about having trouble downloading GitHub and the user is suggesting to directly access the full download link in the browser rather than running the GitHub installer .exe which tries to download that path.  The first comment makes absolutely no sense: the link is an *application*, not a website with content that could be included in the answer.

Somebody should have spent more than 2 seconds handling that post.  The copypasta groups who just blindly apply specific rules without paying any attention to the context are as much to blame here.

Comment: You're right that this post is an answer, but it's really __not obvious__.  Stripped of markup, the answer is `I clicked (something) in IE`, which is still awfully cryptic and non-specific.  And that's barely an answer.  If the answerer had put just a bit more effort into explaining the answer, I'm confident that reviewers would have realized it's an answer.  The other similar answer you linked to included this _very helpful_ and _obvious_ answer `open the URL below in IE`.  No ambiguity there.  In this case, it's not that the link is inappropriate, but that the answer was very unclear.

Answer (score 3):

I get what you're saying but a link to a bug report isn't a great answer.

For example, consider:

Answer 1:

> The problem your having is a bug in technology X, it is documented
>   here: [link to bug report](http://example.com)

VS.

Answer 2:

> The problem your having is a bug in technology X, it is documented
>   here: [link to bug report](http://example.com)
>
> You can work around this bug by doing Y and Z, until the bug is fixed.

While a link to a bug report can be helpful, it doesn't usually solve the asker's real problem. It just leads the asker to ask a followup question about what to do until the bug is fixed.