# Link answers from framework/SDK/tool authors which address the problem

Tags: discussion, link-only-answers

I'm creating this topic bearing in mind the existence of the following threads:

- *[Flagging link-only answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251006/flagging-link-only-answers)*
- *[Some "link-only" answers are actually appropriate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296735/some-link-only-answers-are-actually-appropriate)*

...and numerous other similar instances where perspective, accent and formulation may vary.

---

Perspective of this topic is the following:

**Should we consider "link-only" answers as inappropriate which come from framework/SDK/tool authors and address the problem?**

Here's the example:

*[Swift Compiler Error: Type '[AnyHashable : Any]?' has no subscript members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47669340/swift-compiler-error-type-anyhashable-any-has-no-subscript-members/)*

And here's the response:

[image: Response]

**REASONING**

### 1. Deletion thesis

This answer doesn't contain enough information, elaborated steps or code to be considered appropriate and be regarded as an answer.

### 2. Keep thesis

**Argument 1**

While the question was looking for a code solution or some debugging help, it apparently involved the use of old framework (tool or SDK), which may have (or will have) been the reason of mentioned or other issues. Therefore - since it's a framework (tool or SDK), - answer can't contain code fragments by nature. It may only contain explanation and a good link to use new (stable, updated, fixed) version of the framework (tool or SDK) in question. **Deletion of such answer as inappropriate** may result in decreasing the quality of a solution presented in other answers, which would address older versions of a framework (tool or SDK), neglecting the chance of possible unnecessity of any code solutions at all. Deletion of such answer will bring no benefit to anyone, except may come across as formally correct.

**Argument 2**

While the answer may not meet the question of the OP, it surely does relate to the topic overall. It still remains - at least conditionally - relevant and has positive potential to be helpful long-term. If anyone ever comes across it with similar problem, they may well find this answer more appropriate even though it may be not a to-the-point answer for the present question.

**Bottom line: the answer has relation to the question and contributes to solving it. It should not be deleted.**

### 3. What differs a comment from an answer

Commonly, good comments are recognized as such when provide clarification, advice, useful references, minor code or typo notices and so on. Answer, on the other hand, addresses the problem **directly**, it aims to either solve the problem or dramatically change the vision and approach to a problem. This is where things get subtle. **Link-answers can do both**, they can be a helpful reference or be a solution.

If we stumble across a case, where an answer refers to a newer version of the referenced solution (tool, framework or SDK) and comes from the author of one, should we remove it?
Voting for deletion, **can we guarantee** that non- link-answers, which address older versions of mentioned tool, **are more helpful** than a concise answer, which primarily consists in recommendation and a link to a newer solution?

My understanding of the situation tells me that we shouldn't. What do you think?

I believe many of you saw this comment:

> While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the
> essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.
> Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

This is also the comment left to the mentioned post and is left without any thinking to many similar posts. Rhetorical question: how can you possibly provide "essential parts" of an SDK (framework/tool) in an answer?

Comment: Simple. Litmus test: if the link rots, will the answer still be useful, regardless of it's posted by the author or not?

Comment: 1. If the links were immortal, we'd not discuss this at all.

Comment: 2. If the answer is no longer useful without link, it doesn't mean it is not useful. You can't put the whole source code of your SDK into an answer, you must provide a link.

Comment: On the contrary, you only need to mention the product/library's name/version, and the direct link is a bonus. You might be interested in this post on uber-meta: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). Now, the issue with this specific answer is actually not about the link, but it doesn't help for anyone who can't migrate (for whatever reason) to V2, and it doesn't explain anything about the issue at all, making this an NAA.

Comment: @AndrewT disagree that it is NAA.  I do agree that for someone who can't upgrade, the answer isn't useful, but not being useful is not a deletion criteria which means that NAA is not appropriate.  For someone struggling with a similar problem who can upgrade, it is absolutely a useful answer.

Answer (score 3):

Setting aside the issue of whether the specific answer in question is actually a link-only answer: I don't think it matters at all whether an answer's author is also the author of the framework or tool being asked about.

If the OP's problem is caused by using an old version of the framework, and it would be solved by using a newer version, then an answer that says to use a newer version is perfectly fine. (It doesn't even have to include a link.)

Comment: Agreed. As for whether this specific answer is an actual attempt to answer the question or not, I suppose that depends on whether the author actually believes that the OP's problem is caused by using the deprecated API, or whether they're just trying to make a helpful but tangential suggestion. Unfortunately, the answer as written doesn't really make that clear.

Comment: Unfortunately the author does not tell us how we can solve it with new version or that  there is a bug in old version. I have done my [best](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/360463/5292302), but I real don't see how we can save this "answer"

Answer (score 2):

Let's dissect a paraphrased version of the answer. There's a question:

> Are you using V1?

There's a statement:

> The tutorial you're following uses V1, which is deprecated

And there's a suggestion:

> Use V2 instead, see [link] for a tutorial

We can safely conclude this is definitely not a link-only answer, the flagging for that and the comments complaining about that are all wrong.

Nobody in their right mind would expect an answer stating *"You're using the V1 API, you should be using V2, see [link] for more info"* to have to include the entire step-by-step instructions for using V2 instead of V1. That was not the question to begin with, and the quoted sentence above contains enough information to be an answer on its own.

It **is** however **Not An Answer**. It is a conditional answer, that might be an answer if the answer to the question in the answer is "Yes". Get it?

The question should have been asked in comments (yes, that user has fewer than 50 reputation, not our problem), and if the OP responded positively, the rest of the answer could've been posted as an answer.

Comment: I posted a meta question to get consensus on the topic of your last two paragraphs here, but it devolved into nonsense about picking apart the formatting of my question so I've deleted it. Anyways, I disagree with the last two paragraphs here, and I do not think that represents community consensus at all. Up until this answer there has been absolutely nothing stating that conditional answers are non-answers.

Comment: @Tiny well, that happens to be my opinion. A conditional answer (_"If X is the case, then Y is your solution"_)  would lead me to believe that the question is unclear or incomplete. We should use comments to ask  clarification in that case, not answers.

Comment: Sure, if all you care about is the OP getting their question answered. But if you care about future readers who may end up on the page while in their situation X is the case, preventing such conditonal answers  solely because X turned out to not be the case for the OP would mean that the future reader doesn't get the answer they need. Examples of such answers are everywhere throughout the site.

Comment: What about all of the "I had the same problem, but in my case the solution turned out to be Z." answers? Hell, even "Try this: <code>" answers qualify as answers, and that is of the same basic form of "this might be your solution".

Comment: @TinyGiant that is simply answered as "Z". You don't need to state that you had the same problem.

Comment: Let's not try to answer TinyGiants deleted question in a comment section of another one (although I regret it has been deleted, I thought it was certainly a relevant question). The point is it remains unclear if conditional answers are not answers. In my opinion, the answer in this question is still not an answer, since using a different API sounds like a workaround, and he hasn't stated it's not possible to solve this in the V1 API. It sounds like a general suggestion to improve the code (but might also solve the problem), and thus is a comment in my opinion

Comment: I am sick and f---ing tried of the delete first mentality of the SO community.  A person asked a question, and the **author** of the library offered a potential explanation.  Whether it applies to the OP's specific case or not, it could apply to someone else who has a similar problem and the answer does help them.  Now that it has been deleted, it can't help anyone.  I agree with @TinyGiant that these kind of conditional answers can provide significant long term value.

Comment: I'm glad someone sees the gist. Conditional answer **is** a contribution. Answers are there not to be accepted, they are to be helpful on the raised problem. Answerer is not obliged to cover all circumstances if he can only provide solution for some.

Comment: @psubsee2003 keyword being "could". I do not like throwing suggestions at an unclear problem and seeing what sticks. That's the old forum way. Q&A is supposed to be clear questions with definitive answers.

Comment: @CodeCaster yes, I don't disagree on that aspect (the fact that suggestions don't make for good Q&A), I guess I just disagree on the degree of "could" makes it a valid answer.  For a vague question, you can't throw around suggestions in that manner.  But for a specific searchable question, a user who has this problem would find this solution and be able to try the solution.  In these cases, I would prefer we let the voting sort out the good from the bad answers, and not just delete because someone doesn't like a suggestion.