# Deletion of reasonable link-containing answers / disputed audit

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits

Ever since I came back from my short-term review ban, I was paying extra attention to what and how to review. Whenever unsure, I could hit *Skip* for several times in a row, as [wise people prescribe](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip), and for a reason. Lessons learned and this way I was able to review ~60 posts every day for two weeks, flagging and editing posts.

Previously, I also came here with a [question, related to link-only answers from SDK/framework answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360379/link-answers-from-framework-sdk-tool-authors-which-address-the-problem). I expressed my thoughts on how uncertain that particular case of link-only answers may sometimes be, and received both support and sometimes criticism in the comments, meaning that the issue is disputed, but overall positive score.

And here's another trap I have gotten in:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/18368616

It took me around 30 seconds to decide in favor of *No Action Needed*, and... I'm review-banned again.

Ironically, someone else got in trouble just right after me, having suggested the same solution:

[image: Failed audit]

He is probably banned, too.

And I'm here to dispute this audit and discuss yet another case of link-containing answers.

---

### Reasoning

This question is marked as duplicate of the following:

[Failed and banned for user who answered the question correctly?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288592/failed-and-banned-for-user-who-answered-the-question-correctly)

In the comments, **@gnat** gives the following reference, stating that it applies to the present topic:

> You are expected to take some time to help guide a new user in the first posts review. Clicking 'no action needed' reinforces bad habits when they are there (and doesn't reinforce good ones when they are present with an up vote). You have 20 reviews per day for this queue - it's not a race to get through them. Spending less than 10 seconds per review is not the focus of this review queue.

If this is really the connection point, then it's premature to establish the connection, because it is based on an unproved presumption that I encourage bad habits. **I'm here to explain that I don't**.

### Reflecting the Audit

Above you see the screenshot of the answer in audit.

**Yes**, it contains multiple links.
**Yes**, it doesn't contain any code.

But **NO** — it's more than just a link-only answer. It has suggestions, considerations and multiple links backed with reason, linked together in one context, which **address the question**. For good's sake, it's not just one abandoned link, it shows interest and effort.

This rule:

> If the link expires, answer makes no sense

has very vague, slippery ground. Technologies evolve with time, and render obsolete. So, don't discuss them? If you have question which addresses language of specific version, it may well be no longer actual in a couple of years when a new version comes out. So what is the difference?

It is there. Yes, **link-only** answers should be converted to comments. But this answer is truly a borderline case. It's not just one link and nothing else. As I mentioned above, it has more effort, wider embrace, which results in a post a user could potentially gather wider outlook with. There are three different links, sensibly/contextually connected.

On specific "link-only" case, I strongly encourage everyone to also read this question, where I deepen the reasoning why deleting some of such answers is bad:

[Link answers from framework/SDK/tool authors which address the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360379/link-answers-from-framework-sdk-tool-authors-which-address-the-problem)

As pointed out in that question, this **Delete-first mentality** leads to clearing the site from potentially **helpful** posts. Some cases are disputed, that's true – and this no exception – but can you in all sincerity tell that a particular question is better off without deleted answer? I fail to see this to be the case.

I may have been better skipped this audit, that's also true, but even having failed it, — I
**did not** due to lack of attention, and therefore hoping for some support, with respect to SO community and adopted review audit rules.

Comment: What is the reason in marking the topic duplicate when I come with particular situation? There's no information about the audit I'm here to dispute.

Comment: If you consider that answer to be OK, I am sorry to say but I think that you are rightfully review-banned. If this is an example of your "work", you are not making the site better with your review actions.

Comment: I dunno, maybe because [the answer over there](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288698/839601) fully applies here? "You are *expected* to take some time to help guide a new user in the first posts review. Clicking 'no action needed' reinforces bad habits when they are there (and doesn't reinforce good ones when *they* are present with an up vote).  You have 20 reviews per day for this queue - it's not a race to get through them..."

Comment: @yivi your comment doesn't show any respect. You probably didn't even read the original post. I did explain with attention that I do put **attention** to what and how to review, and **why** I find this particular audit disputed. I have my reasons, even if they are subjective, I may well be wrong. If you disagree, then please bring any reasonable argument instead of going ad-hominem and throwing abrupt "you are not making the site better with your review actions". You have no idea how I review and what effort I put. This shows no respect at all.

Comment: Do not get angry. I'm not attacking you personally, but disagreeing you with your actions. There is nothing disrespectful in my comment. I did read your original post, and your reasoning here. That doesn't change that I think that you chose poorly. And the fact that you still think that the audit is wrong, and not you, shows that you will continue making poor decisions until you decide to change your strategy.

Comment: If you can't take disagreement, you shouldn't bring subjects to meta. I've already told you that the reason I think you will continue to make bad decisions (until you decide to change tack): **you believe that answer is OK and not delete-worthy and your review-ban unjustified**. That tells me you are not learning from this experience, at least not so far. Regarding the answer: try doing the usual exercise of reading that answer as if contained no links. Would you _still_ consider it useful then?

Comment: I can take disagreement if it is disagreement. You don't have to go further and make random assumptions about what-not. Simply stay on-topic, otherwise you are not making the site better with your commenting actions. As for the "usual exercise", as you call it, I see no reason at all to make it. If you believe that answer with multiple links brings no benefit, then try reading the question without that answer. Do you _still_ believe that deletion was helpful?

Comment: Along the same lines, read arguments [in this topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360379/link-answers-from-framework-sdk-tool-authors-which-address-the-problem).

Comment: Yes, I believe that deletion was helpful. I think that answer should be converted to a comment. I believe you were wrong in clicking "no action needed", and rightfully banned, since you are showing a pattern of behavior that's not useful for the site. I already read arguments about this. You should probably inform yourself a little bit more before your review ban is lifted. I'm out. Peace.

Comment: @yivi For what it's worth, I think the comment about your original comment being disrespectful could have been referring to the use of 'work' in quotes. From outside this argument, it seems to be that the tone of that comment is what point 1 in the [be nice policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)  is talking about (and possibly relating to point 2 as well). You may have been right, but I think this user is trying to learn and appears open to doing so, and it's possible the way your comment was written didn't come across in a teaching manner (even if that's what you intended).

Comment: @Tim, if that was the case, I apologize. I used the word "work" to refer to the user's "review actions", which I consider the "work" in question. I still do not believe it is disrespectful or out of line. I'll try to tread more carefully in the future, but I do not think I was wrong; and that the crux of the issue is still valid. I'm sure the user is willing to learn, and will do in time, but right now it seems that what the want is to dispute that this audit is valid, not to learn what do do better in the future; which is the point I was trying to make. Now truly, I'm out.

Comment: And I hear your argument, @yivi. "Answer contains links, without them it's useless". But it is not convincing in this case; by the referred link I explained why.

Comment: _"But it is not convincing in this case"_: Maybe not to you, Hexfire. But honestly, this review really only should've been responded to negatively. If none of the links worked, the answer boil down to: _"Sounds like a `<Vague term>` problem. That's similar to  this other `<vague term>`"_. That's not helpful at all.

Comment: @Cerbrus There are multiple links, backed with reason. The answer suggests and addresses the question. It's not just one link and nothing else. This rule: "If the link expires, answer makes no sense" has very vague, slippery ground. Technologies evolve with time, and render obsolete. So, don't discuss them? If you have question which addresses language of specific version, it may well be no longer actual in a couple of years when a new version comes out. So what is the difference?

Comment: I have edited the question  and voting to reopen it. **If you have reasonable  argumented answer**, I'm ready to hear it. So please vote to reopen and add it below.

Comment: _"If the link expires, answer makes no sense"_ is one of the __foundations__ on which SO is built. Answer shouldn't ever __depend__ on external links. That why reviews __must__ be done assuming __all__ link in the answer are dysfunctional. That's not an opinion. That's __fact__. It's just how the site works. You may not agree, but that doesn't change the review system.

Comment: I want to point something out in @Cerbrus' [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361157/deletion-of-reasonable-link-containing-answers-disputed-audit#comment542930_361157); the answer does not just say "sounds like *<vague term>*, similar to *<other vague term>*". Knowing that a problem is NP-hard (search on Wikipedia) can indeed help in tackling it, especially when knowing that a problem is very similar to some other specific problem (multiprocessor scheduling in the given example). That said, mentioning those is just giving pointers - I agree that should be a comment.

Comment: Yeah, this has been debated time and time again. That answer had useful information in it; most important of all is the *name of the algorithm* the asker is looking for. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). Particularly the part: 'See, this is an answer'. If you don't like the answer, downvote it. But it's not a candidate for LQP deletion.

Comment: @Cerbrus I have drawn parallels with evolving technologies. One solution would no longer make sense after technology goes forward. Nobody is interested in Android v.2 solutions when v.7 is out. This logic makes sense. So why expired links (which, by the time of post are not expired) is such a crime? Particularly, these were multiple links connected contextually, which draw a reasonable post. I repeat that this case is **borderline**, I see reasons **why** it could be regarded as a comment, but I also don't see that it's necessary.

Comment: @Hexfire: Connected contextually by the contents of said links. If the contents are gone, the connection is gone. Your Android analogy doesn't match what's going on here. There are still people using older versions of it. You can't use an older version of a ___dead___ link.

Comment: An answer dealing with an obsolete technology is still useful for anyone that for any reason has to work with that particular technology. That a technology is obsolete doesn't make it magically disappear from the planet. A dead link helps no one.

Comment: @Justastudent: Then the answer boils down to _"Google <Vague term> for more information that may help"_, which still ___doesn't answer the question___.

Comment: @Hexfire: The fact that you haven't __started to consider__ that what we have been saying _may_ have some merit illustrates yivi's earlier point: You are reviewing with the wrong intentions, and seem to be unwilling to change that. This means you ___will___ end up review banned again.

Comment: @Cerbrus This is true, our intentions beg to differ. Delete-first mentality is something I have a hard time to condone with, as I have seen way too many helpful posts deleted in fear that links will expire. I have seen way too many people kicked away when they were attempting to be helpful, but didn't provide code (not enough rep to comment, for example). I find it much more reasonable to mark such answers as obsolete whenever links are gone, not get rid of them immediately as of deadly poison spoiling the site.

Comment: The fact I disagree with your points doesn't mean I don't take them into account and don't take lessons. I don't control any mechanics here, I can potentially only influence them by these posts. But it seems I can't, seeing how many down votes I have got here from delete-first orientated majority.

Comment: And how does one _"Mark an answer obsolete"_? Look, @Hexfire, this isn't a _discussion_ on how the site _ought_ to work. This is us informing you of how the site __works now__. You have some options: ___1.___ Accept that and review accordingly, ___2.___ Reject that, keep reviewing, get banned again, ___3.___ Stop reviewing, post a feature request to change how the site works. That's it. ___No discussion, no buts, no ifs.___

Comment: _"delete-first orientated majority"_ > That's not the mentality on SO. If it were, this post would have been deleted already. There are plenty of people that can cast delete votes on here ___right now___, but there are ___none___.

Comment: I have the clearest idea what my options are. You really don't have to list that. If this isn't the discussion you'd like to take part in, you are free to not. Your point here is clear. My point differs, and that's fine. That also doesn't mean I don't understand the mechanics of review system or reasoning behind it, or how site **works now**, using your wording. However, you gave me good hint about feature request. Perhaps, one day I will formulate it and come up with something sensible I'm trying to catch the right words here. This discussion helped me to polish some thoughts. Thanks.

Comment: Couple of things. 1) we arent saying you did the audit too quickly. Audits arent just to measure speed. They are there to measure accuracy.  2) the answer IS link only. The argument you are making isnt specific to this answer. 'while the link is active,  the information contained is contextually linked to the question' can be said of any link answer that doesn't answer the wrong question. 3) you say you don't encourage bad habits.... but letting users post stuff thay should be comments as answers because they don't have the rep to comment is exactly that.

Comment: With all due respect, Hexfire, the comments made by @yivi don't come off as rude or arrogant to a third party. Try re-reading what Yivi wrote while forgetting completely that the question is your own. The way I read it, it was an instruction as to why you are review banned, and it was qualified with phrases like "I'm sorry to say" and "I think", which shows that Yivi was trying to be polite while showing disagreement. It's a common tactic when someone doesn't want to offend to use "I" phrases, because that puts the burden on the speaker's interpretation and allows discussion.

Comment: The only way to defend yourself against the hostility of this community if you don't post any critical. They decide, what is critical, and they do this quite sensitively. Accepting the most conformist answer won't help. Talking with them in a cooperative tone, even if they clearly don't deserve it, won't help. Nothing helps, except if you retreat - or, if you ride the psychological pressure of the downs, or at least ignore it.

Comment: @peterh: Don't be ridiculous. As with your answer, this is ___not the place___ to vent your personal peeve with how SO works, or your apparent frustration with a negative experience.

Comment: @Cerbrus I think your comment represents very well the general SO attitude for any critical tone.

Comment: @peterh: As I also commented on your answer: Criticism written in a ___unconstructive tone___ is a __rant__. You can disagree with our reception of these rants all you like, but that doesn't change the fact that these rants are unconstructive and not welcome.

Comment: @DavyM I had tough day and my reaction didn’t always help to facilitate the tension. I appreciate your attempt to reconsider yivi's comments. With due respect, however, re-reading them doesn’t help me to not notice bad manner.
Consider it from another perspective: you got in trouble and come to ask for support. You feel lost, and in order to be **constructive**, explain your position, your action and generally provide argument for discussion, **why** you believe your action is valid. 
And what is the first thing you hear back?

Comment: @DavyM You get this: “If you consider that answer to be OK, I am sorry to say but I think that you are rightfully review-banned.” Original post is elaborated enough to receive at least counter argument. What about grounding your “rightfully review-banned”? 
You feel lost and ask for support, **accenting your attention in reviewing** and suggesting ideas for discussion, and…? “If this is an example of your "work", you are not making the site better with your review actions.”. This is flagrant. My “work” is to make proper reviews, which is why I refer my reasoning. That is unfounded arrogance.

Comment: If you are looking for classy answer, refer to the one by Josh below, where point is put across and explained in sober and straight-forward way, right to the point, without any **bold screaming**, and any of those ad hominem arguments, like “you will end up review banned again” or listing someone their options. Compare it to something Cerbrus posts here across multiple comment blocks. He makes points, but the man acts all important and is coming up as an upbringer, with all those edifying, schoolmarmish intonations. This is somewhat ironic – you don’t have to be important to be solid.

Comment: For anyone guessing whether or not I have changed my mind and came to conclusions, and in order to prevent any further debate, – yes, I have changed my mind, _par excellence_. I still _do_ find certain cases of  link-predominantly answers helpful, and this one no exception. However, the concept of a site as a solid/safe resource sounds just as reasonable; as Josh well explained, there's a high bar, and it's worth it. This means that some of those answers should be sacrificed for the greater good. I don't like some facets of it, for a reason, but so far there's no good mechanism to keep them.

Comment: I appreciate everyone's input and efforts in clarification. I decided to keep this question despite hilarious amount of down-votes and ridiculously convoluted lifeline (poor question!). Have fun and Happy New Year. :)

Comment: @Hexfire: The only reason I was writing the way I was, was because that specific user was just being unreasonable. He refused to listen to anything anyone said. You'll find I can be quite pleasant to talk to when the person I'm talking to is pleasant as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Imagine that you've got the same problem as the asker. You click on that inbound Google link and land on this answer. After having read it, do you have a solution? If not a direct solution, do you have the information you were missing, that you need to solve your problem?

*That's* the bar that we should be meeting on Stack Overflow. Yes, it's a high bar. Why should we settle for less? Millions of people rely on this site every day to get stuff done. Should we be just as good as all the other sites out there, or should we be *way better*?

And in the context of a First Posts review, this means that *some* action is needed: at a minimum, a comment, to explain to the first-poster how the answer could be improved. Possibly a downvote, if you don't see a path to improvement.

In another context, sure, maybe no action is needed, but *not* as a First Posts review.

--

Going a little further, the answers to my rhetorical questions, for this post, are obviously "No". Not only does it not directly provide an answer, it doesn't even provide a *pointer* to an answer. It provides pointers to some related information: some terminology, a problem the answerer thinks might be similar, and an academic CS paper about that similar problem.

How does this differ, in essence, from an answer consisting of "You should RTFM: [Foo Programming Guide](http://example.com/rtfmnoob)"?

Comment: Thanks, Josh. This is the most sober and unruffled answer in this thread. I see the point.

Answer (score -20):

The review audits are created from those previous reviews, which are considered very "clear case" by the Stack Exchange software (the decision was very obvious). However, the problem is that even some of these reviews were badly decided. This results that people who gets them as review audits, will fail that audit.

Another important thing: *you need not to review correctly*. Not this is what the review audit mechanism wants from you. The review audit mechanism wants you *to vote always with the majority*.

The reason of the failure of your review audits, and the reason of that the score of your question is now -7 with an ongoing a VtC vote, are exactly the same: this community, as a collective entity, behaves significantly differently what we could call "good-standing" or "rational".

This is also the reason, why the VtC queue cycles around 10k since years, and today there isn't even a plan to ever reduce it. Nobody bothers on that. People capable and willing to review, doesn't do this because *it is simply too dangerous*.

Our reputation system works also as a *social selection mechanism*, focused to filter the high quality *and* active answerers. Unfortunately, there is absolutely no mechanism to filter for good-standing people. I think, this social selection mechanism went somehow mad, and it is an unintended side-effect. However, the Stack Exchange seems to ignore it, or at least they consider it as the lesser evil.

You, an individual, can't do too much. Best if you see that as the private business of the Stack Exchange, Inc - it is up to them, how do they harm their own property, we can't, and shouldn't bother on it.

Another idea: you can be active also on many Stack Exchange sites concurrently. There are some really friendly sites, too, particularly between the smaller ones (and whose topic is unusable to get money).

---

Side note: checking alternative Q&A sites, you can compare the quality of the content. My opinion is that the Stack Exchange is absolutely the best. Practically all the others are flooded with crap. I think, they reach the high quality by filtering also a lot of good content and there is no better option.

Comment: I'm choosing to leave the answer here, but purging the ---75--- 78 comments it had. If it deserves that much discussion, throw it in a question. Now, please don't continue (any of) those arguments here. Chat would work, but keep it civil. I'll lock it if I need to.

Comment: @Undo A lot of worthy comments went away. May I suggest next time a non-destructive alternative (mod movement of comments to the chat)? Typically, mods do this as the first step, and they delete comments massively only if the commenters don't react correctly.

Comment: There wasn't much constructiveness there. I'm opting to give everyone a fresh start discussing this in chat, if they want to.